# Include like clause value in result list

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

I have multiple like clauses on same column in my query.
Is is possible to include the like clause value in result set?
For example

```
SELECT * FROM address ADDR WHERE 
addr.line LIKE '%ONE%' 
OR addr.line LIKE '%TWO%'
OR addr.line LIKE '%THREE%'
OR addr.line LIKE '%FOUR%';
```

The resultset contains all the addresses including  ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR.
Now i would like to see the result set like

```
Address1ONE | ONE
Address2TWO | TWO
THREEaddr   | THREE
```

any clue?
-R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT addr.*,
CASE WHEN addr.line LIKE '%ONE%'  THEN 'ONE'
  WHEN addr.line LIKE '%TWO%'  THEN 'TWO'
  WHEN addr.line LIKE '%THREE%'  THEN 'THREE'
  WHEN addr.line LIKE '%FOUR%'  THEN 'FOUR' 
  ELSE 'Unknown'  -- redundant since other values filtered out by WHERE...
 END AS address_type 
 FROM address ADDR WHERE 
addr.line LIKE '%ONE%' 
OR addr.line LIKE '%TWO%'
OR addr.line LIKE '%THREE%'
OR addr.line LIKE '%FOUR%';
```

Comment: +1. It might be worth migrating the search-list to an actual table that the query can join to.